# htaccess and URL friendly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I'm trying to make a backend for a site to work with URL friendly. What I'm trying to accomplish is that everything after http://account_name/backend will be redirected to `index.php` (and that file will take care of the querystring), but if a user is not logged in, `index.php` will redirect to `login` and that URL should point to a `login.php` file.

At this point if I hit http://account_name/backend, I'm being redirected to http://account_name/backend/login and I see the `login.php` file, but the `js` and `css` recources are not loaded. This resources are beeing called like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Obviously I'm having some path issues, but I can't figure it out. I've tried setting `RewriteBase` in htaccess and `base href` in HTML but with no luck.

Also, I should mention that if try to access a js directly I'm being redirected to

```
http://account_name/backend/js/jquery.js > http://account_name/backend/js/login
```

The files for the front are in:

```
D:\FolderA\FolderB\AccountName\Project
```

The files for the backend are in:

```
D:\FolderA\FolderB\AccountName\Project\backend
```

This is my virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost account_name>
DocumentRoot "D:\FolderA\FolderB\AccountName\Project"
    <Directory "FolderA">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my .htaccess so far:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^[\s/]*$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: How is the user redirected to `<path>/login` pages? None of the given rules is supposed to be doing that.

Comment: @hjpotter92 inside index.php, if session not set: `header("location: login");`

Comment: @hjpotter92 I can also type `http://account_name/backend/login` in the address bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the last rule to recheck file existence:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually problem is your your first rule that is doing `AND`ing rather `OR`ing

```
# if request is for a directory AND
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# if request is for a file AND
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# if request has been rewritten once
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^[\s/]*$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Obviously this rule will **never succeed** as one request cannot be for a file and and a directory at the same time that has already been rewritten (`%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` check).

Due to this rule failing your rule **is actually looping** and being rewritten like this:

1. `backend/js/jquery.js => index.php?route=backend/js/jquery.js`
2. `index.php?route=backend/js/jquery.js => index.php?route=index.php`

After step 2 `mod_rewrite` stops as source and target are same i.e. `index.php`.

Code inside your `index.php` then redirects to `login` as you mentioned in your comment above.

To prevent this behavior you can use rule as suggested by @hjpotter92 above or **fix your first rule** by using `OR` between conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```